# What are these tuberous roots?

Tags: identification, roots

[image]

I bought these at flower show and I can't remember what they are. I also had some freesia and I wondered if these could be Iris.

Answer (score 2):

These look like anemone tubers or corms to me - as to which variety, possibly A. blanda, but not sure, some images and info here https://www.pacificbulbsociety.org/pbswiki/index.php/Anemone